# Implementing timer in Ember CLI quiz app

Tags: ember.js, timer, ember-cli

I am developing a quiz app in ember cli.I have created a dynamic route to load each questions with the URL questions/:q_id.I want to set timer for 30 S for each question.When the timer exceeds 30S it should load the next question automatically and the timer should start from first for the next question.May I know how to implement this feature in Ember.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`ember-concurrency` addon is best choice for this use case.
github : https://github.com/machty/ember-concurrency
docs: http://ember-concurrency.com/#/docs/task-concurrency

You can define `restartable` task and inside wait for 30Sec by using yield

```
taskName: task(function *(){

  //Have condition for exiting
  yield timeout(30000);
  //transitionTo other question after 30Sec

}).restartable()
```

Comment: It is showing some error in console stating that transitionToRoute  is not a function.

Comment: Make sure `this` refers to  controller object, since `transitionToRoute ` is available only for controller object. To ensure, you can write  `debugger` statement in code and inspect or using `console.log(' this object',this)`

Comment: May be you can update your question which throws error.